# Problems running Glassfish

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I tried to start Glassfish in debug mode but I get the following Error:

```
    Error occurred during initialization of VM
    agent library failed to init: jdwp
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
    ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it in Domain Admin Consol Glassfish
configuration>JVM Settings>Debug enabled und debug option : -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **-XX:MaxPermSize=192m** entry from your glassfish domain located at glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml. and then run the command to start server domain i.e. asadmin start-domain.

[domain.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DfBg.png)